# Removing items in a set

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, input, numbers, set

I have a function that takes a set, prints the min/max, and then asks the user to remove items  in the set until the set is empty.

My code:

```
def deleteFromNumSet(numsSet):
    while len(numsSet)!=0:
        print("Max is",max(numsSet),"and Min is", min(numsSet))
        num=input("Enter a number between the two.")
        if num in numsSet:
            print("The number is in the set.")
            numsSet.remove(num)
        else:
            print("The number is not in the set.")
    return("No more numbers left in the set.")
```

The code will say that the "number is not in the set", regardless of whether or not it actually is in the set. It worked using the emulator on repl.it (which was where I coded it originally), but it does not work on my Python program (I am currently using version 3.4.1). I would like to know why it worked on the (older) version of python but does not work now, and a solution that would work for current versions of python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input()` returns a **string**, not an integer. If our set contains integers then Python will not consider the string equal to the numbers.

Convert the input to an integer first:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number between the two."))
```

In Python 2.7, `input()` is a different function; it essentially does the same as `eval(input())` would do in Python 3. As such it automatically interprets digits as a Python integer literal.

To make your code work in both Python 2 and 3 would require a lot more experience with both versions. See the [Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/pyporting.html) how-to if you really want to go this way.

Comment: why would the  code not work in both python 2 and 3 by just casting   input to an int?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I don't know what *other* code is in the OP's program that isn't so easily made portable. The `print()` function calls need `from __future__ import print_function` at the top, and there probably are other, hidden issues as well. In other words, helping the OP make this code work across 2.x and 3.x is way too broad. Rather than say: this code will work on both versions, I rather state that that task may be too big a hurdle for the OP at this point.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: and that is ignoring the fact that in Python 2 you really should use `raw_input()`. I'd have to explain about the dangers of `eval`, show how to create portable code with a `try`, `except NameError` setup, etc. etc. and it quickly becomes a huge slippery slope.

Comment: Yes, a slippery slope indeed but as is, just casting to int would work on both.

Comment: Well, the code works now at least; thanks for the follow up as to the difference between versions.